# Cannot invoke a private method on a generic type T

Tags: java, stack

I want to expand stackArray for a post fix evaluator. If the number of elements pushed (push method) in the array stack exceeds the stack length, the expand() method will double the length of the array stack and also copy all the elements in arrayStack to stackExtend. My error message is that I cannot invoke the expand method on the generic type T in the push method.

```
    private void expand(){
    // TODO Implement this method.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] stackExtend = (T[])new Object[stackArray.length*2];

        for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_LENGTH; i++) {
            stackExtend[i] = stackArray[i];
        }
        stackArray = stackExtend;
    }

    @Override
    public void push(T elem){

        if (top == stackArray.length) {
            stackArray.expand();
            stackArray[top] = elem;
            top++;
        }
        else {
            stackArray[top] = elem;
            top++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't see your line numbers.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Arrays don't have an `expand()` method.

Comment: What I think @shmosel means is "you have a typo - `stackArray.expand();` should just be `expand();`".  In other words, call the `expand` method on the current object, not on its `T[]` field.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I meant what I said. But you're probably right about OP's intent. :)

Comment: myself and a friend solved it by creating a temp array and copying the elements. I have other questions about handling exceptions but I cannot post

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the `push` method as follows.

```
@Override
public void push(T elem){

    if (top == stackArray.length) {
        expand();
    }

    stackArray[top] = elem;
    top++;
}
```

So this is eliminating some duplicated code.

But more importantly, `expand` is a method that you want to call on the current object, not a method of the array type.  So it's a mistake to reference the `T[]` array when you call it.

Just writing `expand()` calls the method on the current object.